# How can I update an attribute that's added to a method via a decorator?

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

I've created a decorator that wraps tkinter's `after()` method to make looping functions easier (i.e., having a function call itself periodically)

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import wraps


# decorator
def after_loop(interval: int):
    """Loop the decorated method at the specified `interval` using `after()`"""
    def _after_loop(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            value = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.after(
                interval,
                lambda s=self, a=args, k=kwargs: wrapper(s, *a, **k)
            )
            return value
        return wrapper
    return _after_loop
```

This works perfectly fine as written above...

```
# example tkinter application
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('After Loop Test')
        self.label_val = 0
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_val)
        self.label.pack()
        self.label_update  # begin updates
    
    @after_loop(1000)  # update this label every second
    def label_update(self):
        self.label_val += 1
        self.label.config(text=self.label_val)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

however, I'm struggling to implement an abstraction around `after_cancel()` so the user (I) can cancel the loop if desired. I've tried the following:

```
def after_loop(interval: int):
    """Loop the decorated method at the specified `interval` using `after()`"""
    def _after_loop(function):
        function.loop_cancel = False  # add attribute to decorated function
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            value = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            _loop_id = self.after(
                interval,
                lambda s=self, a=args, k=kwargs: wrapper(s, *a, **k)
            )
            if wrapper.loop_cancel:  # break out of the 'after' loop when set
                self.after_cancel(_loop_id)
            return value
        wrapper.loop_cancel = False  # add attribute to the wrapper function
        return wrapper
    return _after_loop
```

But when I attempt to write to the `loop_cancel` attribute flag, I'm greeted with `AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'loop_cancel'` even though it shows up in `label_update`'s `__dict__` and I can read the attribute's value just fine with `print(label_update.after_cancel)`

```
@after_loop(1000)  # update this label every second
def label_update(self):
    self.label_val += 1
    self.label.config(text=self.label_val)

    # test reading the 'loop_cancel' attribute (works as expected)
    print(self.label_update.loop_cancel)  # => False
    print(self.label_update.__dict__)  # => {'loop_cancel': False, ...

    # attempt to set the 'loop_cancel' flag and break out of the loop (no dice!)
    if self.label_val >= 5:
        self.label_update.loop_cancel = True  # raises AttributeError
        # setattr(self.label_update, 'loop_cancel', True)  has the same problem
```

Are attributes added via a decorator inherently read-only, or am I implementing the decorator incorrectly somehow? Any help is much appreciated, as ever.

---

*Edit* - to say that if I *don't* add the `loop_cancel` attribute to the function immediately inside `_after_loop` the `AttributeError` is raised immediately upon trying to access `self.label_update.loop_cancel`, which isn't entirely surprising.

```
def _after_loop(function):
    function.loop_cancel = False  # add attribute to decorated function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.label_update` produces a new `method` object every time it is evaluated, so the attribute you set is only for *that* bound method. You need to set the attribute on the underlying `function` object itself.

```
@after_loop(1000)  # update this label every second
def label_update(self):
    self.label_val += 1
    self.label.config(text=self.label_val)

    if self.label_val >= 5:
        self.label_update.__func__.loop_cancel = True
```

This shouldn't be a problem as long as you have only one instance of `App` in your program. If that's not the case, you can always store a `dict` of flags (one flag per wrapped method) on the instance itself and have the wrapper look there, instead of on the wrapper, for the flag.

```
def after_loop(interval: int, tag: str):
    def _after_loop(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            value = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            _loop_id = self.after(
                interval,
                lambda s=self, a=args, k=kwargs: wrapper(s, *a, **k)
            )
            if self._loop_tags.get(tag):
                self.after_cancel(_loop_id)
            return value
        return wrapper
    return _after_loop
```

Then

```
@after_loop(1000, "foo")
def label_update(self):
    self.label_val += 1
    self.label.config(text=self.label_val)

    if self.label_val >= 5:
        self._loop_tags["foo"] = True
```

Comment: This works, but having to call the `__func__` dunder gives me pause - I don't suppose there's a more user-friendly way to obfuscate this?. And if you don't mind, could you elaborate on implementing the dict of flags? I don't anticipate having more than one root application instance, but flexibility is nice. I appreciate the answer! Also: `print(self.label_update.__func__)` returns the same ID each time - it's still a different instance?

Comment: I'll add the dict to the answer. You don't really *need* to use `__func__`; you could hard-code a reference to the function with `App.label_update.loop_cancel` as well. (But then you have an issue if you override `label_update` in a subclass.)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now - it's because the method `label_update` exists in an *instance* of  the `App` class! That makes sense - thanks for the lightbulb moment. Since my decorator has access to `self`, can it access the instance of the decorated function this way somehow?

Comment: Well, not quite. `label_update` is an ordinary function assigned to a *class* attribute. It's the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that turns `my_app.label_update(...)` into `App.label_update(my_app, ...)`. The bound method is a temporary object that wraps both the instance invoking the method and the actual function in a new callable value that takes *its* arguments and adds them to the explicit arguments in an explicit call to the function.

Comment: Well that is quite the rabbit hole. Thank you for taking the time to explain things so clearly!

Comment: Heads-up: The dictionary flag method doesn't appear to work as-written, but I'll play around with it.

Comment: Hm, at the very least I forgot to actually create the `_loop_tags` attribute anywhere.

Comment: I think that's it - no worries, I get the idea! Thanks again!